# well pressure switch in barn, pressure tank in house

Tags: switch, well, pressure

My well control setup is in the unheated barn. I tried to keep the pump room heated for a few years but am tired of replacing pressure tanks that freeze up over the winter due to electricity being lost.  I'm wondering what would be wrong with keeping the pressure switch where it's at (easier to drain in fall) and putting the pressure/bladder tank in the house. What do you think?

Comment: Where is the well fed from (power)?  is there a controller for the well other than the pressure switch? Submersible pump? More info is needed if the well is fed from the house this may be an easy change but if a setup like my barn I have a separate feed to my barn that would be a much more involved change.  just about anything can be done if money is no object.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the whole circumstance of what you want to do or the complete set-up of piping & control, allow me to say that the location of the bladder tank does not matter as long as you can control the operation of the well pump. I think that the best answer would be to bury the water line between the barn and house deep enough to prevent it from freezing and to move the tank and pressure switch to he house.  You could dig a trench and put the water line and any wiring in that trench. This way nothing will freeze.

Answer (score 0):

That should work but DO NOT place a valve between the pressure tank and pump. If it is closed it will cause the pump to oscillate possibly blowing lines or burning out the pump. You could add a second switch if that would make you more comfortable. d.george is correct at this point his is the best solution.

You are not alone, farmers other others in the colder climates with a well have the same problems. It is not uncommon to place the well near the barn as the bulk of the water was for the stock. There are a lot of solutions, none are the best in all situations. Ours was close to the house so a small addition was added as a back porch and a pump house which was kept warm.